# Is there a config file that controls the microphone?

Tags: configuration

Corollary questions:

- What is the location of the file?
- Can it be used to deactivate the microphone?

This is for a Dell Latitude laptop.

Comment: Would you rather disable it / blacklist it permanently?

Comment: Just disabling would be enough.

Comment: Did you try disabling it on Settings > Sound > Input ? The microphone is "controlled" by a kernel module, you could just disable the module for your laptop mic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "pulseaudo" to achieve this purpose:

```
amixer -D pulse set Capture nocap
```

turns your mic off.

You can simply put it anywhere which will be run at start up, e.g: `.profile`.

If you want to turn it "on" again use:

```
amixer -D pulse set Capture cap
```

and for toggling between on and off:

```
amixer -D pulse set Capture toggle
```